# Open with - is there something similar for iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

In Android I can for example open mp4 files in user's apps from my own app (using Intents). In the next example - intent for playing a video:

[image]

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(newVideoPath));
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(newVideoPath), "video/mp4");
startActivity(intent);
```

Is there something similar for iOS? Can I open from my app for example url (of video) in Photos, VLC or another player (which are installed on iPhone/iPad)

if yes, any example in `Swift`?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the documentation for [Document interaction programming](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010409-SW1).

You can register file types that your app supports/can handle and then when a user selects a particular file from the files app or downloads from another app the system will offer a list of apps that can open this file, including yours.

Comment: My app records videos in mp4, only this file type I need to play with any user preinstalled app which can play videos (Photos, VLC,...). I will look at documentation, but I mean it's easy to find examples for Android, no examples for iOS at all?

Comment: ah then in that case you more than likely want to look at [UIDocumentInteractionController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentinteractioncontroller). I dont know of any examples, I haven't needed to do this in iOS yet

Answer (score 0):

[UIActivityViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivityviewcontroller) might fit your needs.

For example,

```
let url = // URL to your .mp4 file
let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [url], applicationActivities: nil)
present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: `2018-02-27 16:44:22.028603+0200 ExampleApp[1408:759585] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Your application has presented a UIActivityViewController (<UIActivityViewController: 0x103080a00>). In its current trait environment, the modalPresentationStyle of a `

Comment: fixed by `activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view`, but anyway  - this is for file sharing and it displays many apps

Comment: Yeah, it won't give you open in video apps only, but you can mess around with `activityVC.excludedActivityTypes` to remove some of those options (like email, post to Facebook/Twitter, etc.) to maybe suit your needs better. Activity type documentation is here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiactivitytype

Comment: I mean it doesn't give me anything but copy, I guess iOS just doesn't really have such option, only for sharing/copying

Comment: Yes, iOS is a bit more restrictive than Android. It's also worth noting that in order for apps to show up in this list, their developers need to implement those capabilities from their end.

Comment: as you see VLC for Android did it (and all other players)